# behat find field error: Call to undefined method LoginAuthContext::find()

Tags: php, behat, mink

I'm writing the behat step definition to automate the submission of the user name and password fields on the following "Sign In" page. I got the following error by using the xpath selector. Please advise what I did wrong? Thanks!!

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method LoginAuthContext::find() in
>   /behatlogin/features/bootstrap/LoginAuthContext.php on line 20

Sign In Form

```
<form action="/auth" method="POST" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required="" autofocus="">
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block shadow1" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

LoginAuthContext Step Definitions

```
/**
 * @When /^I am logged in$/
 */
public function iAmLoggedIn()
{
    $this->find('xpath','uname')->setValue('testuname');
    $this->findField('xpath','pass')->setValue('testpass');
    $this->pressButton('Sign in');
}
```

Comment: This seems to be php error, not javascript. Add relevant tags to get help from concerned person.

Comment: add your context class and behat file. Do you extend from correct class?

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you don't extend the right class and you cannot see the `find()` method in the current class.

Using an IDE editor can help you prevent these kind of issues because it should give you hints with the available methods in that class.

For example if you are using page objects your `LoginAuthContext` needs to extend `Page`, else for the classic approach I think you need to extend `Context`.

Comment: I added `use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;` and `use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page;` but still gives error `Fatal error: Trait 'Behat\Behat\Context\Context' not found ` and `Fatal error: Trait SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page not found`

Comment: Please check the documentation of page objects https://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/working_with_page_objects.html

Comment: do you have good examples? I tried that but still not working